# What's enough to prove $H\leq G$ where G is a group and $ H\subseteq G$?

Tags: group-theory

> Let G be a group and $H\subseteq G$.
>
> To show that $H\leq G$ is checking the identity is in H, the inverses are in H and H is associative under the binary operation of G $(*)$ equivalent to checking the identity is in H, the inverses are in H and H is closed under the binary operation of G $ (**)$?

I realized my instructor uses $(*)$ and $(**)$ interchangeably . Are they equivalent and are these enough to prove $H\leq G?$

Comment: What do you mean by "$H$ is associative" and "$H$ is closed"?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I edited it

Comment: It is still not clear. How can $H$ be associative under some action? Associativity is a property of a function (i.e. the binary operation), not a subset. This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: No, they're not equivalent.  The associative property comes from $G$ already.  Probably if your instructor skips the closed step, they are assuming it's obvious, or they want you to fill in the details.

Comment: So should I show all the four properties in order to show H is a subgroup of G?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Of course they are not equivalent, because the statement "$H$ is associative under binary opeartion" simply **doesn't make any sense**.

Comment: @LeylaAlkan $H$ is a subgroup if it contains the neutral element and $gh^{-1}\in H$ whenever $g,h\in H$. So I'd say 2 properties? There's nothing else to check. You may want to make 3 out of them: $gh\in H$ and $g^{-1}\in H$. But 4?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I think you must have a 'typo' above -  didn't you mean  "if your instructor skips the ASSOCIATIVE step, they are assuming it's obvious" (because associativity holds in the ambient $G$)?

Comment: I guess I have confused this with showing something is a group. So yes yours is also correct and it is also fine if I show neutral element in H, inverses are in H and H is closed under the induced operation from G @freakish I saw now my instructor hasn't used associativity for proving subgroups :)

Comment: @LeylaAlkan That actually makes me happy. Someone teaching such thing would be a disaster.

Comment: @peterag No, I meant to say closed.  Although it does technically leave the proof unfinished, I can think of pedagogical and practical reasons why it happens.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's be careful.  Suppose $G$ is a group with operation $\cdot$, and $H$ is a subset of $G$.  We say $H$ is a *subgroup* of $G$ provided $H$ is a group *under the same operation*.  In particular, $\cdot$ needs to be a binary operation on $H$.  That means $h_1 \cdot h_2 \in H$ for all $h_1, h_2 \in H$.  This property is often summarized by “$H$ is closed under the operation $\cdot$.”

The other group axioms are: the operation needs to be associative, you need an identity, and you need inverses.  Since you dealing with a larger group $G$, all of those axioms hold within $G$.  Since $G$ is a group, $\cdot$ is associative.  If $H$ is closed under $\cdot$, then the associative property of $\cdot$ *automatically* holds in $H$.

[I am assuming that this is what you meant by “$H$ is associative under $\cdot$.”  Freakish is right that this isn't a precise statement:  Associativity is a property of *operations*, not a property of *sets*.  When it comes time to write things or say things formally, make sure you keep this distinction.]

Next we have to check whether $H$ has an identity element.  Since $G$ is a group, we know $G$ has a identity element, so we really just need to show that that identity element is in $H$ too.  Likewise for inverses—any $h\in H$ has an inverse which *a priori* belongs to $G$; we must show it is in fact in $H$.

To summarize, these are necessary and sufficient conditions for $H$ to be a subgroup of $G$:

1. $H$ is closed under the operation $\cdot$.
2. The identity element $e \in H$.
3. For all $h \in H$, its inverse $h^{-1} \in H$.

Based on what you're describing, it seems that when your instructor is showing that a subset is a subgroup, sometimes they discuss the associative law and sometimes they discuss closure.  I wasn't in the room, but I can imagine that happening.

If the instructor checked that the set is closed under the operation, that the identity is in $H$, and inverses of elements in $H$ are also in $H$, than this is enough to prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.  We don't need to check that the operation is associative; that comes from $G$.

If the instructor checked that the operation is associative, the identity is in $H$, and the inverses are in $H$, but skipped checking that the subset is closed under the operation, then it's an incomplete proof.  The associativity check is not important to the subgroup proof; it follows automatically.  Perhaps they illustrated it just to reinforce that $G$ was a group.  Why did they skip the closure step?  It's plausible they wanted you to verify this on your own, or that it was obvious and they didn't want to bother writing it down.  I do this frequently.  Note that these two cases can often be the same—if the instructor says something is obvious and it's not obvious to you, you should definitely verify it on your own and ask your instructor if it's still not obvious!

As an example for why closure is necessary, consider $G= \mathbb{Z}$ under addition and $H=\left\{-2,0,2\right\}$.  Then properties 2 and 3 are satisfied, but not 1.  And this $H$ is a not a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Note that it is possible that $(ab)c$ is computable in a subset of $G$ but $a(bc)$ isn't. If the subset is closed under the operation, then $bc$ will be in the subset and associativity will work.

Answer (score 0):

These are not equivalent; $(*)$ and $(**)$ both need to be shown. The thing is, (**) implies $ (*)$ since the operation is closed, so all you need to show is $(**)$ to show H is a subgroup of G (and inverses/identity). On the other hand, $ (*)$ is absolutely pointless since, for example, I can take an arbitrary subset of a group and check if the operations are associative, but whether the operation's value is contained in the subset (that is, closed in the subset) is not understood.